Audio analysis to recognize most exciting sport game highlights
I am working on a project where I have retrieved a bunch of highlight videos for a basketball game. These highlights include every basket made, assists, blocks etc. Because these highlights in total are like 15-20min long, I want to implement some algorithm to recognize the most important ones. One of my ideas was to somehow use audio analysis, because the more exciting the highlight, the higher the chance that crowd or commentator will make higher noise.
After investigating I found that this is not so easy, but I implemented 2 functions to measure 1) loudness and 2) peak_Db for each video highlight.

Loudness:

import soundfile as sf
import pyloudnorm as pyln

def extract_video_loudness(self, audio_filename):

#get video loudness and store in dict
data, rate = sf.read(audio_filename) # load audio (with shape (samples, channels))
meter = pyln.Meter(rate) # create BS.1770 meter
loudness = meter.integrated_loudness(data) # measure loudness

return loudness


peak_Db:

def extract_audio_peak(self, audio_filename):
    # Open the audio file
    with wave.open(audio_filename, 'r') as audio:
        # Extract the raw audio data
        raw_data = audio.readframes(audio.getnframes())

    # Convert the raw audio data to a list of integers
    print(raw_data)
    print(len(raw_data))
    print(audio.getnframes())
    samples = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=audio.getnframes()*2), raw_data)

    # Find the peak sample
    peak = max(samples)

    # Calculate the reference value based on the bit depth of the audio file
    reference_value = 2**(audio.getsampwidth() * 8 - 1)

    # Calculate the peak value in dBFS, using the maximum possible sample value as the reference value
    peak_dB = 20 * math.log10(peak / reference_value)

    return peak_dB

I am using both of these return values to then sort highlights by importance, where the loudest and highest peak_Db means more important highlight. However, even though technically this code works, after testing the results I don't really see that they would work as I would want to. E.g., some videos, where crowd in the arena plus the commentator goes crazy because of impressive moment, are measured as not so loud and also peak_Db seems to be about average compared to other videos. Meanwhile some standard play has very high loudness and peak_Db, although when checking the highlight I can see that it is pretty standard play and crowd nor the commentator aren't making any big noise. Thus it seems that I can't really rely on this code to sort out most important highlights.
So my question is - could you guys help me with any ideas what I could use or maybe how to tweak my already existing code to get more precise results?
Also I had an idea about using some AI stuff, but I have never been coding anything with AI and also I could not find anything on internet what could help me. I will appreciate any ideas or information!

The best way would be to create a small dataset, of say 100 clips, with the time of the events of interest.
Then you can probably use an audio model like YAMNet, OpenL3, PANNs or similar to get an embedding vector representation of the audio. Then use KNN or LogisticRegression to identify "cheer" type moments. This is a machine learning approach, with pre-trained feature extraction.
